# Why flow around an airplane is different in different frames of reference

Tags: fluid-mechanics, aerodynamics

In the book **Fluid Mechanics by Yunus Cengel** it was written

**"Flow around an airplane, for example, is always unsteady with
respect to the ground, but it is steady with respect to a frame of reference
moving with the airplane at cruise conditions."**

So my question is that why does this happens? And does this has anything to do with moving and stationary control volume?

Comment: Do you understand the what steady and unsteady flows are?

Comment: @PhilSweet perhaps if words like laminar and turbulent are checked out as well.

Comment: @Phil Sweet In steady flows the streamlines don't change their shape with time and the properties of the flowing fluid don't vary with time but in unsteady flows the streamlines change their shape with time as well as the properties of the fluid aren't constant with respect to time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to the ground, an airplane tears up the air it goes through - the disturbance isn't uniform it's unsteady, it moves across the world.

With respect to the airplane, the air flows around it the same way all the time.  Airflow around the plane is uniform and steady.